# Auto-py-to-exe not working because of some weird missing module

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I've used auto-py-to-exe in the past, I've had issues with it but ultimately it worked fine and I made a few .exe files which worked as intended. However, today testing it again for a project nothing worked.

I tried converting the simplest files, and even something I've converted in it before which worked in the past, but they all just instantly closed when I tried to run them. I opened the converted files through cmd and got this:

> [8020] Module object for pyimod02_importers is NULL! Traceback (most recent call last):   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 22, in <module>   File "pathlib.py", line 14, in <module>   File "urllib\parse.py", line 40, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipaddress' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 17, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimod02_importers' [8020] Failed to execute script 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception!

I tried uninstalling and installing auto-py-to-exe again, but this issue persisted. I'm sure there's a simple fix, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: do you have this missing file ? `pyimod02_importers`

Comment: It sounds like you python installation might have been corrupted.  Try reinstalling python

Comment: @D.L Not from the error message, but it's in pyinstaller on github and I tried installing both pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe, it's supposed to come with them.

Comment: @Alexander the file which is missing is from pyinstaller, so it should be an issue with that. I may try to reinstall python itself, then I'll report back. Although honestly I'm considering to just use another converter because it's been nothing but trouble with these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem a while ago but forgot to post the answer, so here it is:

Apparently Pyinstaller just doesn't work with newer versions of python right now, I apologise for now knowing exactly which version is needed, but I am still on python 11, just a lower version. I'll try to update the answer if I find the other thread where it stated the specific versions.